# Get content page field value

Tags: 7, nodes, tokens

I have a content page contain three field. Number A: Number B and Total Number. During add content page, I fill up Number A: 20 and Number B: 30. How to let Total Number auto display 20 + 30 = 50?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by content page? if it is the node page and the fields name are `field_number_a` and `field_number_b` then install [entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module and in the `template.php` and in `hook_preprocess_node` function and write this:

```
function YourTheme_preprocess_node(&$var){
    if($var['node']->type == "YOUR_CONTENT_TYPE"){
          $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$var['node']);
          $a = $wrapper->field_number_a->value();
          $b = $wrapper->field_number_b->value();
          $var['total'] = $a + $b;
    }
}
```

Then in the node page you can use `$total` variable as the sum of the `a` and `b`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Interesting, I will try, but I dun understand $total. Just key this in the total_number field?

Comment: No field for the `total` is needed. In the node page, variable `$total` is available. Before the loading any node page drupal looks for `THEME_preprocess_node` function to run, when it finds it, it runs the function and after finishing the function, node page will be loaded. `$var` is array of values that is available in the node page, I only added new value to this array, `$var['total']` defines a new value in to the array and this value is available through `$total` variable in the node page.

Comment: I very new to these drupal code. Is there any tutorial for beginner?

Comment: Search the google for video series `Drupalize.me - Theming Basics For Drupal 7 Series` you can also find its free tutorials on youtube too. Its torrent is also available

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save the data also in field(Total Number) then you can use [hook_node_presave](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) for save the data in fields.
example :-

```
function yourmodule_node_presave($node){
    //check your content type
    if($node->type == 'page'){
          // check fields are having values
         if(isset($node->field_a['und'][0]['value']) && isset($node->field_b['und'][0]['value']))
         $node->field_total_number['und'][0]['value'] = $node->field_a['und'][0]['value'] + $node->field_b['und'][0]['value'];
    }
}
```

or 
if you want to display on create page auto upate the field(total number value) after enter the values in field_a and field_b,
you can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) and update value using ajax.

also you can check example module for form alter and how to update fields automatically

Answer (score 0):

[Computed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/computed_field) module can be used for this purpose. It provides an option to define custom fields in the content type and derive their values based on other fields. It also gives you an option to either store the computed value to the database or calculate them on the fly.

The method suggested by @Drupalist computes it on the fly and is invoked before displaying the node page only. This method is not helpful if you intend to use the computed field(total_number) in a view for example.

Comment: I had install this module and enable it. I take a look at the content type and nothing is change. I not sure where to start. Can you guide me? Many Thanks.

Comment: Nothing changes just by enabling the module. You would need to create the new field (Ex: Total) with the field type as computed.In the field setting you will then have the option to insert your own php code to compute the value of this field based on other fields. For code samples and other details refer to the module documentation.