# Creating a new variable by combining 2 field values

Tags: theming

In my theme’s preprocess node function i’m trying to create a new variable by combining 2 existing fields, both of which are text strings. 
pseudo code is this:

$teachers_name = $firstname + $lastname;

When looking at a print out of the Teacher object using Devel, i see the field first name is an array, structured like this…

```
field_first_name
    und
        0
            safe_value ‘Lisa’
```

but so far it’s not working at all. i’m not accessing the variables correctly.

```
function myTheme_preprocess_node(&$variables){
    if($variables['type']=='teacher') {
        $variables['teachers_name'] = $variables['field_first_name’][‘und’][0]    [‘safe_value’];
    }
```

how can i access the text string of field 'first name'? thanks!

Comment: This answer shows how to properly access node field values in the preprocess node function: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/28283/10729 - If that helps you solve your issue this probably should be closed as a duplicate of that one.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/entity) module and `entity_metadata_wrapper` . I already answered a similar question in [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/154861/get-content-page-field-value/154872#154872).